# Python .whl Could not find a version

Tags: python, pip

I am really new to python so open for tips.

I am trying to add .whl to my python, so I moved it to my scripts folder then opened cmd and went to the script path.

And typed `pip install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32 and pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32`.

But when I do that it gives me this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.
```

For both files the same error. How do I fix this I have no idea.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should reference the file i,e, `pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`

Comment: To explicitly state what Peter was implying, you are missing the .whl extension on the end of the file.

Comment: Yup that worked I am stupid. Thanks! If you post that I can mark you're anwser.